# Partially decompress and estimate size of actual decompressed data message

Tags: java, zip, compression, lossless-compression

I have a simple requirement wherein I want to drop or not process a message if it exceeds an upper limit of X bytes. However the sender is allowed to compress the message and send. The compression entropy is highly varying in case the user creates a random message with say all 0s or 1s etc . However assuming a trusted sender is there a way to peek a compressed message and estimate its actual size on decompression. I am using the Zip protocol using java.util.zip but I am open to any solution in other libraries or languages .

Comment: If you're only worried about "trusted" users sending sensible messages, why not just use a fixed approximation?

Comment: Trust but verify :) On a more serious note , I meant trust as in the message won't be a spam or DOS message , but the user can say sandwich a very large XML or PDF inside the message . Rarely the message will exceed MAX limit we set.

Comment: And how would you be able to tell that by peeking? If there's some catastrophic decompression, you can't find it until it's happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really.

Deflate is a streaming format, it doesn't know anything about the data before it starts, so it can't embed the decompressed size (formats like snappy, brieflz, and some others do).

Probably the best you'll be able to do is use the streaming API to decompress at most `MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE` bytes (you may need to use `MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE + 1`; with zlib it's hard to tell whether the end of the stream was reached or if it simply processed all the input available unless you give it enough room to actually decompress more data).  This will not let you stop processing *early* if you think the message will be too long, but will let you stop as soon as the message really is too long (which should be sufficient to mitigate a DoS).

Unfortunately you can't just estimate the total size based on what you've seen because someone could easily have data which is hard to compress at the beginning of the stream, then a million identical bytes which will be *extremely* well compressed.